# Как написать геометку как в Яндекс такси с использованием yandex MapKit?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Как мне написать такую точку выбора местоположения как в Яндекс такси с использованием yandex MapKit , помогите пожалуйста примером кода
Пока изучаю, но ничего особо не получилось[image: введите сюда описание изображения]